# How to copy some record from a table to another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables and I want to copy some records from table1 to table2

```
Table1: field1,field2,field3,field4
Table2: f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6

INSERT INTO Table2 (f1,f2)
SELECT field1,field2 FROM Table1
WHERE Table2.f3=1234;
```

but I have this error

```
ORA- 00904: STRING: invalid identifier tips
```

How can I set a WHERE condition for Table2? I have to insert these records only if f3 from Table2 is equal a certain value

Comment: `WHERE Table1.f3=1234`?!?

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields...

Comment: Are you sure it is about INSERT and not about UPDATE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Assume you need the below based on the structure of your query

```
 INSERT INTO Table2 
 SELECT field1,field2,f3,f4,f5,f6 FROM Table1,Table2
 WHERE Table2.f3=1234
 and Table2.f3=Table1.field3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `update` and you can do it as follows:

```
UPDATE Table2 
   SET (f1,f2) =  (SELECT field1,field2 
                     FROM Table1 
                    WHERE <JOIN CONDITION BETWEEN TABL1 AND TABLE2>)
 WHERE Table2.f3=1234;
```